# Custom order of activities in GetStream

Tags: getstream-io

From the docs, *The activities in the feed are sorted on a UUID based on time.*

But is this the only way to sort? Perhaps I can pass a time attribute with the activity and sort based of of an attribute like the notification feed? I ask this because yesterday, I ran into this error:

```
A SocketError occurred:
Hostname not known: us-east-api.getstream.io
```

And the push to GetStream (using the ruby on rails gem) had to be retried. I'm pretty sure this caused the "old" activity to be placed on top of the stack as a "new" activity. Perhaps there is a way to push an activity into the middle of the feed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ranked feeds to get more control over the sorting:
https://getstream.io/docs/#custom_ranking
It's very powerful, pretty similar to how you define ranking in something like ElasticSearch. It's only available on paid plans though.

You'll also want to look into updating your activities:
https://getstream.io/docs/#activity-update

Note that our aggregated and notification feeds are sorted based on the last update. This is different from the flat feeds that are sorted on a simple time.

How would you like your sorting to work?

Comment: Most likely sorted on when the activity was saved into our database. It seems like custom ranking is the way to go here because the activity cant currently be updated because it wasn't pushed to begin with. Do you have any info on how to prevent this error in the first place?